Selenium click is intercepted
I need a little help with html read/interpretation.
I have this code here:


<html><head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="author" content="Christoph Lukas Lindtner">
        <meta name="designer" content="Christoph Lukas Lindtner">
        <meta name="description" content="eiCAB - This is 4G">
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
        <link rel="icon" href="/img/app/icons/favicon.png" type="image/png">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <title>HMI8462-TW • C0118828</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="cbd179784e6e85707d5d648d84e84f25732d1e7e1594916ea75f3de455036850.css" type="text/css">
            <script type="application/javascript" src="4fa2c0563949d618857f54c5c23b5e66caad69ba2dc66ccaeeeb0e3fc7b622df.js"></script>
        <script src="blob:http://10.80.100.10/2462b3eb-e47d-448f-8734-d67637cb8842"></script></head>
    <body class="st connected" role="application" id="madpenguin"><div role="progressbar" class="orbit" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><canvas width="80" height="80"></canvas></div><div class="ui-workplace-overlay" style="width: 1349px; height: 932px; display: none;"></div><div role="main" style="height: 932px; width: 1289px;"><div role="toolbar" class="action-bar" style="width: 1289px;"><div role="button" class="action-control-box"><div class="label" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div><div role="img" class="action-back" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M18.5 12.5H7.3l5.2 5.4 -0.6 0.7L5.5 12l6.3-6.5 0.6 0.7 -5.2 5.4h11.2V12.5z" fill="#878787"></path></svg></div><div role="img" class="action-bar-icon"></div><div role="img" class="action-drawer-control" style="transform: translate3d(24px, 0px, 0px); top: 18px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#95A5A6" d="M18.5 13h-13v-2h13V13zM18.5 17h-13v2h13V17zM18.5 5h-13v2h13V5z"></path></svg></div></div><div class="action-bar-title" role="heading" aria-level="1" style="width: 392px;"></div><div role="menu" class="action-menu" aria-level="1" aria-posinset="1" style="width: 681px; z-index: 651;"></div><div class="notification-bar"><div role="button" class="widget link online"><div role="img" class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="enable-background:new 0 0 24 24;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
    .st0{fill:#9E9E9E;}
]]>
</style>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M14.112,6.34c1.017-0.6,2.331-0.484,3.181,0.367c0.955,0.954,0.988,2.493,0.116,3.539l0.01,0.009    l-0.178,0.178l-3.377,3.376l-0.023,0.023c-1.041,1.042-2.713,1.065-3.726,0.054c-0.57-0.57-0.812-1.349-0.728-2.107l-2.239,2.239    c0.18,0.551,0.463,1.064,0.852,1.517l0.233,0.233c1.883,1.884,5.137,1.694,7.253-0.422l0.316-0.316l3.019-3.018    c2.087-2.087,2.252-5.317,0.368-7.201c-1.883-1.883-5.113-1.718-7.2,0.369l-1.24,1.24C11.868,6.067,13.04,6.038,14.112,6.34z"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M9.887,17.66c-1.016,0.6-2.33,0.483-3.18-0.367C5.752,16.339,5.719,14.8,6.59,13.754l-0.009-0.009    l0.178-0.178l3.376-3.376l0.023-0.023c1.042-1.042,2.713-1.065,3.726-0.053c0.57,0.57,0.812,1.349,0.729,2.107l2.239-2.239    c-0.18-0.551-0.463-1.065-0.852-1.517l-0.233-0.233c-1.884-1.883-5.137-1.695-7.253,0.422L8.199,8.97L5.18,11.988    c-2.087,2.087-2.252,5.317-0.369,7.2c1.884,1.884,5.114,1.719,7.201-0.368l1.24-1.241C12.132,17.933,10.96,17.962,9.887,17.66z"></path>
    </g>
</g>
</svg></div><div class="label" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div></div><div role="button" class="widget-notifications widget"><div role="img" class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M10.2 18.7c0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1 0 1.8-0.8 1.8-1.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0-1.8 0-1.8 0S11.2 18.7 10.2 18.7zM19.5 16.6c-0.4-1.1-1.6-2.4-2.5-3.8 0 0 0-0.1 0-0.1 0-4.2 0.2-5.2-1.1-7.2C14.6 3.5 12 3.5 12 3.5s-2.6 0-3.9 2c-1.3 2-1 3-1.1 7.2 0 0 0 0.1 0 0.1 -0.8 1.4-2 2.8-2.5 3.8 -0.1 0.3 0 1 0.6 1.1 0.4 0 13.2 0 13.6 0C19.4 17.6 19.6 16.9 19.5 16.6z" fill="#E0E0E0"></path></svg></div><div class="label" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div></div></div></div><div class="application-background"></div><div style="height: 872px; width: 1289px;"><div role="form" class="update-layout vertical" style="overflow: auto; height: 872px; width: 1289px;"><div><div role="heading" aria-level="1" class="vertical">Update device software</div><div class="notes paragraph vertical"></div><div class="sw-update-info paragraph vertical">The configured device type is a crucial variable in the software update process. Make sure that the software update you want to deploy is intended for the configured device type.</div><div class="paragraph vertical">Select one or more packages and perform a manual update</div><div role="list" class="software-packages vertical"></div><div class="actions vertical"><div role="button" class="action-select-file standard grey"><div role="img" class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#9E9E9E" d="M6.7 6.4v10.8h10.8V6.4H6.7zM15.1 14.8H9V8.7h6.1V14.8zM9.5 5.5V3.7c0-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.4 -0.2 0-0.4 0.2-0.4 0.4v1.8H9.5zM15.5 5.5V3.7c0-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.4 -0.2 0-0.4 0.2-0.4 0.4v1.8H15.5zM12.5 5.5V3.7c0-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.4 -0.2 0-0.4 0.2-0.4 0.4v1.8H12.5zM14.7 18v1.8c0 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.2 0 0.4-0.2 0.4-0.4v-1.8H14.7zM8.6 18v1.8c0 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.2 0 0.4-0.2 0.4-0.4v-1.8H8.6zM11.7 18v1.8c0 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.2 0 0.4-0.2 0.4-0.4v-1.8H11.7zM5.8 14.4h-1.8c-0.2 0-0.4 0.2-0.4 0.4s0.2 0.4 0.4 0.4h1.8V14.4zM5.8 8.3h-1.8c-0.2 0-0.4 0.2-0.4 0.4 0 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.4 0.4h1.8V8.3zM5.8 11.3h-1.8c-0.2 0-0.4 0.2-0.4 0.4s0.2 0.4 0.4 0.4h1.8V11.3zM18.4 9.1h1.8c0.2 0 0.4-0.2 0.4-0.4 0-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.4h-1.8V9.1zM18.4 15.2h1.8c0.2 0 0.4-0.2 0.4-0.4s-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.4h-1.8V15.2zM18.4 12.2h1.8c0.2 0 0.4-0.2 0.4-0.4s-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.4h-1.8V12.2z"></path></svg></div><div class="label" style="">Select files</div></div><div role="button" class="action-reboot standard grey" aria-disabled="true"><div role="img" class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#95A5A6" d="M12.7 13.2h-1.2V3.5h1.2V13.2zM15.4 3.5v1.6c0.3 0.2 0.5 0.3 0.8 0.5l0.6-1.3C16.4 4 15.9 3.7 15.4 3.5zM18.5 8.7l1.3-0.4c-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.9-0.6-1.3l-1.1 0.9C18.3 8.2 18.4 8.4 18.5 8.7zM19.1 10.6l1.4 0.2c0-0.5-0.1-1-0.3-1.5l-1.3 0.4C18.9 9.9 19 10.2 19.1 10.6zM19.1 11.6c0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.4 0 0.8-0.1 1.1l1.2 0.9c0.1-0.6 0.2-1.2 0.2-1.8L19.1 11.6zM12 19.1c-3.9 0-7.1-3.3-7.1-7.4 0-2.8 1.5-5.3 3.7-6.5V3.5c-3 1.4-5.1 4.5-5.1 8.1 0 4.9 3.8 8.9 8.5 8.9 3.7 0 6.8-2.4 8-5.8l-1.2-0.8C17.9 16.9 15.2 19.1 12 19.1zM17.6 7.1l1.1-0.9c-0.3-0.4-0.7-0.8-1.1-1.2l-0.6 1.3C17.2 6.6 17.4 6.8 17.6 7.1z"></path></svg></div><div class="label" style="">Reboot device</div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="notification-hub" style="overflow: auto; height: 932px; width: 350px;"><div class="label title-bar">Info-Hub</div><div role="button" class="action-close"><div role="img" class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M17.9 17.2c0.2 0.2 0.2 0.5 0 0.7C17.8 18 17.7 18 17.5 18s-0.2 0-0.3-0.1L12 12.7l-5.2 5.2C6.7 18 6.6 18 6.5 18c-0.1 0-0.2 0-0.3-0.1 -0.2-0.2-0.2-0.5 0-0.7l5.2-5.2L6.1 6.8C6 6.6 6 6.3 6.1 6.1 6.3 6 6.6 6 6.8 6.1l5.2 5.2 5.2-5.2c0.2-0.2 0.5-0.2 0.7 0 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.5 0 0.7L12.7 12 17.9 17.2z" fill="#95a5a6"></path></svg></div><div class="label" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div></div><div></div></div><div role="dialog" class="network-error red" style="left: 471.156px; top: 276px;"><div class="label title-bar">Connection lost</div><div role="img" class="title-bar-icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve" style="width: 80px; height: 80px;"><path fill="#E9453A" d="M10.4 19c0-0.4 0.1-0.8 0.4-1.1 0.3-0.3 0.7-0.4 1.2-0.4s0.9 0.1 1.2 0.4c0.3 0.3 0.4 0.7 0.4 1.1 0 0.4-0.1 0.8-0.4 1.1C12.9 20.4 12.5 20.5 12 20.5s-0.9-0.1-1.2-0.4C10.5 19.8 10.4 19.4 10.4 19zM13.2 15.4h-2.4L10.5 3.5h3L13.2 15.4z"></path></svg></div><div role="form" style="height: 178px; width: 404.688px;"><div role="heading" aria-level="1" class="vertical">The connection to the device has been lost</div><div class="paragraph vertical">The connection will be re-established automatically. Please wait a moment.</div><div class="failed paragraph vertical" aria-hidden="true" style="visibility: hidden;"></div></div><div class="actions"><div role="button" class="action-refresh standard"><div role="img" class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#95A5A6" d="M10.7 20.5l0.9-1.1c-2.5-0.1-4.8-1.4-6.1-3.6 -1.5-2.6-1.3-6 0.6-8.4 0.1-0.2 0.4-0.2 0.6-0.1 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.6 -1.7 2.1-1.9 5.1-0.5 7.4 1.1 1.9 3 3 5.1 3.2l-1-0.8 1.2-0.1 1.5 1.3 -1.3 1.5L10.7 20.5zM17.8 16.6c1.9-2.4 2.2-5.7 0.6-8.4 -1.3-2.2-3.6-3.5-6.1-3.6L13.3 3.5l-1.2 0.1 -1.3 1.5 1.5 1.3 1.2-0.1 -1-0.8c2.1 0.2 4 1.4 5.1 3.2 1.4 2.3 1.2 5.3-0.5 7.4 -0.1 0.1-0.1 0.3 0 0.5 0 0 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1C17.4 16.8 17.6 16.8 17.8 16.6z"></path></svg></div><div class="label" style="">Restart App</div></div></div></div><div class="action-drawer" style="overflow: hidden;"><div><div class="profile-box"><div role="img"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"><path d="M14 12.7c-0.6 0.3-1.2 0.5-2 0.5 -0.7 0-1.3-0.2-1.9-0.5 -2.5 2-5.3 5.5-4.7 6.9 0.6 1.2 12.5 1.2 13 0C19.1 18.4 16.5 14.6 14 12.7zM8.2 9.7c0.5 1.7 2 3 3.8 3 1.8 0 3.3-1.2 3.8-3H8.2zM16.6 9.2c0 0 0-0.9-0.3-1.2 0 0-0.1 0-0.2-0.1 -0.1 0-0.3-0.1-0.3-0.3 0-0.3-0.1-2.5-2.4-3.3 0 0-0.3 0.3-0.6 2.7l0-3.2c0 0 0-0.2-0.1-0.3C12.5 3.5 12.5 3.5 12.4 3.5c-0.2 0-0.8 0-0.8 0s-0.1 0-0.1 0c-0.1 0-0.1 0.1-0.1 0.3 0 0.4 0 3.2 0 3.2s-0.4-2.4-0.7-2.7c0 0-2.3 0.6-2.4 3.2C8.3 7.8 8.2 7.8 8 7.9c-0.1 0-0.2 0.1-0.3 0.2C7.4 8.4 7.4 9.2 7.4 9.2h0.7 7.6H16.6z" fill="#808285"></path></svg></div><div class="label info-box">Admin </div></div><div role="menu" class="drawer-menu" aria-level="1" aria-posinset="1" style="z-index: 651; width: 320px;"><div role="menuitem" class="quicklinks-database" id="ACTION_DATABASE"><div role="img" class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#2196F3" d="M12 3.5c-3.6 0-6.5 1-6.5 2.2v3.3c0 1.2 2.9 2.2 6.5 2.2s6.5-1 6.5-2.2V5.7C18.5 4.5 15.6 3.5 12 3.5zM12 7.5c-2.9 0-5.2-0.8-5.2-1.8 0-1 2.3-1.8 5.2-1.8 2.9 0 5.2 0.8 5.2 1.8C17.2 6.7 14.9 7.5 12 7.5zM12 12.2c-3.4 0-6.2-0.9-6.5-2.1C5.5 10.2 5.5 10.3 5.5 10.3v3.3c0 1.2 2.9 2.2 6.5 2.2s6.5-1 6.5-2.2v-3.3c0-0.1 0-0.1 0-0.2C18.2 11.3 15.4 12.2 12 12.2zM12 16.9c-3.4 0-6.2-0.9-6.5-2.1C5.5 14.9 5.5 14.9 5.5 15v3.3c0 1.2 2.9 2.2 6.5 2.2s6.5-1 6.5-2.2v-3.3c0-0.1 0-0.1 0-0.2C18.2 16 15.4 16.9 12 16.9z"></path></svg></div><div class="label">Database Manager</div></div><div role="menuitem" id="ACTION_SETTINGS" class=""><div role="img" class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M19.1 12c0-0.4 0-0.8-0.1-1.2l1.5-1.4c-0.2-0.6-0.4-1.1-0.7-1.6l-2 0.1c-0.5-0.7-1-1.2-1.7-1.7l0.1-2c-0.5-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.6-0.7L13.2 5c-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.1-1.2-0.1 -0.4 0-0.7 0-1 0.1 -0.1 0-0.1 0-0.2 0l-0.7-0.8L9.4 3.5c-0.1 0-0.1 0-0.2 0.1 -0.5 0.2-1 0.4-1.5 0.6l0.1 2c-0.7 0.5-1.2 1-1.7 1.7l-2-0.1C3.9 8.3 3.7 8.9 3.5 9.4L5 10.8c-0.1 0.4-0.1 0.8-0.1 1.2s0 0.8 0.1 1.2l-1.5 1.4c0.2 0.6 0.4 1.1 0.7 1.6l2-0.1c0.5 0.7 1 1.2 1.7 1.7l-0.1 2C8.2 20 8.6 20.2 9 20.3c0.1 0.1 0.3 0.1 0.4 0.2l0.2-0.2 1.2-1.3c0.4 0.1 0.8 0.1 1.2 0.1 0.4 0 0.8 0 1.2-0.1l0.8 0.9 0.5 0.6c0.6-0.2 1.1-0.4 1.6-0.7l0-0.2 -0.1-1.8c0.7-0.5 1.2-1 1.7-1.7l1.6 0.1 0.5 0c0.3-0.5 0.5-1.1 0.7-1.6L19 13.2C19.1 12.8 19.1 12.4 19.1 12zM12 17.3c-2.9 0-5.3-2.4-5.3-5.3 0-2.9 2.4-5.3 5.3-5.3 2.9 0 5.3 2.4 5.3 5.3C17.3 14.9 14.9 17.3 12 17.3z" fill="#2196F3"></path></svg></div><div class="label">Settings</div></div><div role="menuitem" id="ACTION_UPDATE_SOFTWARE" class="state-active"><div role="img" class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#2196F3" d="M10.7 20.5l0.9-1.1c-2.5-0.1-4.8-1.4-6.1-3.6 -1.5-2.6-1.3-6 0.6-8.4 0.1-0.2 0.4-0.2 0.6-0.1 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.6 -1.7 2.1-1.9 5.1-0.5 7.4 1.1 1.9 3 3 5.1 3.2l-1-0.8 1.2-0.1 1.5 1.3 -1.3 1.5L10.7 20.5zM17.8 16.6c1.9-2.4 2.2-5.7 0.6-8.4 -1.3-2.2-3.6-3.5-6.1-3.6L13.3 3.5l-1.2 0.1 -1.3 1.5 1.5 1.3 1.2-0.1 -1-0.8c2.1 0.2 4 1.4 5.1 3.2 1.4 2.3 1.2 5.3-0.5 7.4 -0.1 0.1-0.1 0.3 0 0.5 0 0 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1C17.4 16.8 17.6 16.8 17.8 16.6z"></path></svg></div><div class="label">Update Software</div></div><div role="menuitem" id="ACTION_USER_MANAGER"><div role="img" class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#9E9E9E" d="M16.3 19.6c-0.6 1.2-11.8 1.2-12.3 0 -0.6-1.4 2-4.9 4.4-6.9 0.5 0.3 1.1 0.5 1.8 0.5 0.7 0 1.3-0.2 1.9-0.6C14.4 14.6 16.9 18.4 16.3 19.6zM10.2 4.5c-2.1 0-3.8 1.8-3.8 4s1.7 4 3.8 4c2.1 0 3.8-1.8 3.8-4S12.2 4.5 10.2 4.5zM15.7 11.6c-0.6 0.3-1.2 0.6-1.9 0.6 -0.1 0-0.2 0-0.3 0 2.3 2 4.8 5.8 4.2 6.9 0 0.1-0.2 0.2-0.3 0.3 1.4-0.1 2.4-0.4 2.6-0.7C20.6 17.4 18.1 13.6 15.7 11.6zM15.4 8c0 1.5-0.8 2.8-1.9 3.5 0.1 0 0.3 0 0.4 0 2.1 0 3.8-1.8 3.8-4 0-2.2-1.7-4-3.8-4 -0.7 0-1.3 0.2-1.8 0.5C13.9 4.3 15.4 5.9 15.4 8z"></path></svg></div><div class="label">User Management</div></div><div role="menuitem" class="action-logout" id="ACTION_LOGOUT"><div role="img" class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#7F8C8D" d="M14.8 5v1.3c1.8 1 3.1 3.1 3.1 5.4 0 3.4-2.6 6.1-5.9 6.1 -3.2 0-5.9-2.7-5.9-6.1 0-2.3 1.2-4.3 3.1-5.4V5C6.7 6.1 5 8.7 5 11.7c0 4 3.1 7.3 7 7.3 3.9 0 7-3.3 7-7.3C19 8.7 17.3 6.1 14.8 5zM11.6 5h1v8h-1V5z"></path></svg></div><div class="label">Logout</div></div></div></div></div><div role="dialog" class="log-dialog white"><div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; overflow: auto;"><div><div role="list"></div></div></div><div class="empty-box"><div class="label" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div></div><div class="actions"><div role="button" class="action-ok standard"><div class="label" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div></div><div role="button" class="action-cancel standard"><div class="label" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div></div></div></div>
<span style="white-space: nowrap; position: absolute; left: -3900px; width: auto; height: auto; z-index: 10000; display: inline-block; font: 21.3333px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">null</span></body></html>



Using python-selenium I want to click a side bar called Database Manager
As said I'm not so expert so I tried this code:
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@class='drawer-menu']//child::div[1]//div[text()='Database Manager']").click()

but it drives me into an error
Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="label">...</div> is not clickable at point (111, 102). Other element would receive the click: <div role="heading" aria-level="1" class="vertical">...</div>

can anyone explain me what is wrong with my code?

What is the element that is intercepting the click? <div role="heading" aria-level="1" class="vertical"> Did you figure that out yet? A link to the page would really help here.

I've tried to add more html code.

We can't see your HTML anymore. Please fix the formatting of the question. Also, the HTML you added is mismatched... not all tags are closed, etc. Please fix that also.

Can you post a link to the page?

it is a private page so unfortunately I can't but i've adjusted the code now. it should be visible

The HTML which you have added now only has <head>, no <body>

now it should work. sorry I realized only now the chance to add the html code in a different way

@martinmistere When you post HTML of any size, you really need to use an HTML beautifier like this to fix the indents otherwise the HTML is just unreadable.

is not clickable at point (111, 102). Other element would receive the click: <div role="heading" aria-level="1" class="vertical">...</div>

As the exception suggests, selenium is not able to click on desired element(Database Manager) because, some other element is overlaid on the desired element. Without the access to the actual page, I cannot tell how exactly you can get rid of the covering element. But here are the few things you can try:

Not sure you have maximised the window, sometimes maximising the window will not cause any obstruction. Try this in your code if you haven't tried already. driver.maximize_window()

Use Action Chains to interact with the menu and sub-menus. Instead of Selenium's click() method try using ActionChain's move_to_element method. Sample code is below:


from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

# Create actions object
actions = ActionChains(driver)
# Store the desired element into a variable called element
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@class='drawer-menu']//child::div[1]//div[text()='Database Manager']")
# Click on element using ActionsChains
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()


Use Explicit Wait. Sample code is below:

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

...

# Create wait object with 10s wait time
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# Below line will wait for 10s until the state of the desired element is clickable
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='drawer-menu']//child::div[1]//div[text()='Database Manager']"))).click()


Use Javascript to perform click, instead of Selenium's click(). Sample code below:

import time

...

time.sleep(5)
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@class='drawer-menu']//child::div[1]//div[text()='Database Manager']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)


with the 3th option instead I'm getting: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (111, 102). Other element would receive the click: ...
so it seems it is not a matter of how much we wait

I've already "maximized" the window using the code driver.set_window_size(1920,1080).
the action 2 makes something (it is not seen as an error) but it doesn't open the "side window" at it should do.

In option 2, try this - actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()

no same error as before. it seems the command is correct but the side window is not opened/shown

What about option 3 and option 4?

option 3 gives the error Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (111, 102). Other element would receive the click: ...
while option 4 seems the command is accepted but again the side window is not opened/shown

Did you generate this using ChatGPT?

I didn't downvote but ChatGPT answers are banned on the site. I'm assuming that's why people are downvoting it. I don't know why they think it's created by ChatGPT. Having said that, 1 is a good suggestion, 2 will not fix the issue because it still clicks, 3 will not fix the issue because it's going to report as clickable, it's still blocked by the overlaying element, 4 is reasonable but I would use it as a last resort. The best thing is to figure out what the overlaying element is and remove or move it, if possible.

I am very well aware about ChatGPT policy on SO. People are down voting based on their assumption. Some at least put their assumption in the comment. Thanks for your point to point feedback. Re. 3. sometimes if you wait, the obstructing element will disappear or go away from the view(talking from personal experience), hence explicit wait is one option we can always try for this exception. I understand about your feedback specific to element_to_be_clickable which will report clickable. JS option was intentionally put as option 4 signifying it as last resort. Agree with your last sentence.

@Shawn For #3, I have method that handles clicks in my framework. It does so by waiting for clickable inside of a loop that traps stale element and click intercepted exceptions and loops again until the timeout in seconds. That (usually) does take care of temporarily blocked elements like you are talking about... but won't handle the permanently blocked cases.
